# Como hacer un INSERT de un Array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Muy Buenas...

Se realiza la consulta a la db, dicha consulta solo muestra los id de ingresos que estan en la tabla 1 que se llama (INGRESOS) y no estan en la tabla 2 (FACTURACION) se colocó un chuekbox donde el usuario escoge a cual de ellos le va a ingresar el codigo de factura, ingresa el codigo de factura y su estado. (El usuario puede tomar de la lista de 1 a 10 ID(Checkbox)
al enviarlo a la DB, con un `print_r($_POST);` muestro por pantalla lo que me manda y me muestra esto ---

```
Array ( [chekbox] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 19 [2] => 12 [3] => 15 [4] => 14 [5] => 13 [6] => 17 [7] => 11 [8] => 16 [9] => 10 ) [num_fac] => 2222 [estado_fac] => 1111 )
```

Que deseo en que me puedan ayudar ? poder ingresar todos ya sean 1 o 10 según necesidad o criterio del usuario junto con los dos campos que son codigo de factura y estado de factura.   de Antemano Gracias

```
<?php

  $strsql = "SELECT cod_ingreso, nombre, apellido, cedula, fecha, formacion, nivel, empresa, num_fac FROM ingresos LEFT OUTER JOIN facturacion ON (cod_ingreso=ingreso_cod) WHERE ingreso_cod is NULL AND fecha ORDER BY fecha ASC LIMIT 10";

  $rs = $mysqli ->query($strsql) or die (mysqli_error());
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
  $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

?>
   </div> 

<hr>
<div style="width:1400px; height:500px; overflow:auto;">
<div class="col-xs-14 col-sm-14 col-md-14 " align="center">
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="900" align="justify" class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover'>
    <tbody>  
        <theader>
        <tr>
              <th width='100px'>Cod. Ingreso</th>
              <th width='180px'>Nombre</th>
              <th width='180px'>Apellido</th>
              <th width='160px'>Cedula</th>
              <th width='160px'>Fecha</th>
              <th width='130px'>Nivel</th>
              <th width='150px'>Empresa Temporal</th>
              <th width='150px' align="center">Checar</th>

    </tbody>          
<?php if ($total_rows > 0) {
        do {
?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width='100px'><?php echo($row['cod_ingreso']); ?></td>
        <td width='180px'><?php echo($row['nombre']); ?></td>
        <td width='180px'><?php echo($row['apellido']); ?></td>
        <td width='160px'><?php echo($row['cedula']); ?></td>
        <td width='160px'><?php echo($row['fecha']); ?></td>       
        <td width='130px'><?php echo($row['nivel']); ?></td>
        <td width='150px'><?php echo($row['empresa']); ?></td>
        <td width='150px' align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chekbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['cod_ingreso']; ?>"></td>

    </tr>
<?php
        } while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs) );
        mysqli_free_result($rs);
    } else {
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No data found.</td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
      <label-success for="nombre"><h4>Codigo de factura</h4></label-success>
      <input type="text" class="form" id="num_fac" name="num_fac">
      <label-success for="nombre"><h4>Estado de la Factura</h4></label-success>
      <input type="text" class="form" id="estado_fac" name="estado_fac">      
   </section> 
   <br>
    <br>
       <div class="acciones">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Guardar">Guardar</button>
      </div> 
</form>
```

### Esta es la tabla donde se ingresaran los datos ..`-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla`facturacion`

```
CREATE TABLE `facturacion` (
  `ingreso_cod` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Factura Generada a:',
  `oingreso` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Orden de Ingreso',
  `num_fac` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Numero o Consecutivo de factura',
  `estado_fac` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Estado de la Factura'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci COMMENT='Facturacion';
```

---

--

### -- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `ingresos`

```
CREATE TABLE `ingresos` (
  `cod_ingreso` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Cedula',
  `nombre` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primer Nombre',
  `nombres` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Segundo Nombre',
  `apellido` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primer Apellido',
  `apellidos` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Segundo Apeliido',
  `tipo_ced` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tipo de Cedula',
  `genero` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `pais_nac` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `f_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo_sangre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `formacion` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `g_sangre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel_edu` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `sector` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `cargo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel_l_e` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_social` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `o_servicio_ext` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `empresa_temp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `alergia` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `enfermedades` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `lesiones` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `medicamentos` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `n_contacto` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo_factura` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tipo de Factura',
  `tel_contacto` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `c_contacto` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `doc_cumple` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `text_cumple` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_modifica` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci COMMENT='Table de Ingresos';
```

`
Sus respectivos Indices.

### -- Indices de la tabla `facturacion`

```
ALTER TABLE `facturacion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`num_fac`),
  ADD KEY `ingreso_cod` (`ingreso_cod`);
```

### -- Indices de la tabla `ingresos`

```
ALTER TABLE `ingresos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_ingreso`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `cod_ingreso` (`cod_ingreso`);
```

Comment: Podrías serializar el Array a J y luego guardarlo en la BBDD como una cadena

Comment: @Jakala Muy Buenas ... Gracias por tu respuesta .. Me ayudarías a hacer eso que comentas ?

Comment: @Jakala .. Según tu aporte comento: 
<?php
$serialized_data = serialize(array([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]));
$var1 = unserialize($serialized_data);
var_dump ($var1);
?>
Esto muestra en pantalla: array(10) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(3) } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(5) } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(7) } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(8) } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(9) } } {"error":true}..
Como guardo en mysql ?

Comment: Alguien podría echarme una mano con este tema ?

Comment: @Jakala Aquí atento ...

Comment: seria algo como:  $valorAGuardar = json_encode($myarray, true);   Despues de esto $valorAGuardar es una cadena de caracteres y la puedes guardar en tu campo de bbdd. Cuando lo necesites leer, haces   $myArray = json_decode($valorDeBBdd, true);

Comment: @Jakala Muy buenos días de verdad gracias por contestar. lo que hasta ahora tengo:
<pre>
<?php

print_r($_POST);
?>
</pre>
<?php
$fact = $_POST['num_fac'];
$estado = $_POST['estado_fac'];

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$value)
for ($i = 0; $i < $value; $i++) {
$string = "INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, num_fac, estado_fac ) VALUES ";
 $string.="('".$value. "', '".$fact."', '".$estado."'),";        
    }
Me guarda un solo valor, un solo ingreso y estoy haciendo 10. NO seguí con el serialize pues de verdad me estanque bastante. Espero tu valiosa ayuda.

Comment: @Jakala esto me imprime en pantalla:
Array
(
    [checkbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 12
            [4] => 15
            [5] => 14
            [6] => 17
            [7] => 16
            [8] => 11
            [9] => 10
        )

    [num_fac] => 2222
    [estado_fac] => PENDIENTE
)
INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, num_fac, estado_fac ) VALUES ('10', '2222', 'PENDIENTE'),{"error":false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de 2 días intentando de muchas formas y maneras ya lo logré, comparto para aquellos que estén en la misma necesidad de ayuda. Este es el archivo que gestiona el formulario que anteriormente coloqué.

$string));
$cadena_final = substr($string, 0, -1);
$cadena_final.=";";

$msn = header("location:/HMC/html/factura/fac_dinamica.php");

if ($mysqli->query($cadena_final)):
echo json_encode(array($msn => false));

else:
echo json_encode(array('error' => true));

endif; 

 $mysqli ->close();

?>